# Plotting multiple lines in the same graph for every different entry in a column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My dataset looks like this:

```
Town    week     price    sales       
A         1       1.1      101
A         2       1.2      303
A         3       1.3      234
B         1       1.2      987
B         2       1.5      213
B         3       3.9      423
C         1       2.4      129
C         2       1.3      238
C         3       1.3      132
```

Now I need make a single figure with 3 lines (each representing a different town), where I plot the sales and price per week. I know how to do it when I take the mean of the towns, but I can't figure out how to do it per Town.

```
data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")

dfEuroAvg = data[data['Product'] == "Euro"].groupby('Week').mean()

t = np.arange(1, 50, 1)

y3 = dfEuroAvg['Sales']
y4 = dfEuroAvg['Price']

fig, ax2 = plt.subplots()

color = 'tab:green'
ax2.set_xlabel('Week')
ax2.set_ylabel('Sales', color = color)    
ax2.plot(t, y3, color = color)
ax2.tick_params(axis = 'y', labelcolor = color)

ax3 = ax2.twinx()
color = 'tab:orange'
ax3.set_ylabel('Price', color=color) 
ax3.plot(t, y4, color=color)
ax3.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2.set_title("product = Euro, Sales vs. Price")
```

EDIT: On the X-axis are the weeks and on the Y-axis are the price and sales.

Comment: What do you want your X and Y axis to be ?

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to mention that. The X-axis are the weeks and the Y-axis is the price and sales.

Comment: @Feederofbruurs: Check the answer and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing it using `groupby` to form groups based on `Town` and then plot the `price` and `sales` using a secondary y axis

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

df_group = data.groupby('Town')['week','price','sales']

ylabels = ['price', 'sales']
colors =['r', 'g', 'b']

for i, key in enumerate(df_group.groups.keys()):
    df_group.get_group(key).plot('week', 'price', color=colors[i], ax=ax, label=key)
    df_group.get_group(key).plot('week', 'sales', color=colors[i], linestyle='--', secondary_y=True, ax=ax)

handles,labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
legends = ax.legend()
legends.remove()
plt.legend(handles, labels)

ax1.set_ylabel('Price')
ax2.set_ylabel('Sales')
```

[image]

Comment: Works amazing! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to fetch the data for each town separately by filtering the dataframe.

```
# df = your dataframe with all the data

towns = ['A', 'B', 'C']

for town in towns:
    town_df = df[df['town'] == town]
    plt.plot(town_df['week'], town_df['price'], label=town)

plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Week') 
plt.ylabel('Price') 
plt.title('Price Graph')
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

I have done this for the price graph, you can similarly create a graph with Sales as the y-axis using the same steps

Answer (score 0):

You may plot the pivoted data directly with pandas.

```
ax = df.pivot("week", "Town", "price").plot()
ax2 = df.pivot("week", "Town", "sales").plot(secondary_y=True, ax=ax)
```

Complete example:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u = """Town    week     price    sales       
A         1       1.1      101
A         2       1.2      303
A         3       1.3      234
B         1       1.2      987
B         2       1.5      213
B         3       3.9      423
C         1       2.4      129
C         2       1.3      238
C         3       1.3      132"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(u), delim_whitespace=True)

ax = df.pivot("week", "Town", "price").plot(linestyle="--", legend=False)
ax.set_prop_cycle(None)
ax2 = df.pivot("week", "Town", "sales").plot(secondary_y=True, ax=ax, legend=False)

ax.set_ylabel('Price')
ax2.set_ylabel('Sales')
ax2.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The `legend=False` didn't work for me and that's the reason I had to first remove the legends and then set them to the legends of the first plot where I explicitly use `label=''...`